# add entry to .csv file

Tags: text-processing, csv

i already have a .csv file with this structure:

```
Phone_number,name,size
2223178555, Joshep, 22.36
```

and i would like to add this entry taken from a .dat file that looks like this:

```
PN: 2221471162
Cesar
size: 14.22
```

so the .csv looks like this:

```
Phone_number,name,size
2223178555, Joshep, 22.36
2221471162, Cesar, 14.22
```

Could you please help me with this?

Thanks

using the marked solution this is what I've got:

```
Phone_number,name,size
2223178555, Joshep, 22.36
2221471162,Cesar,14.22
```

I've tried placing "\t" before printf's

```
awk 'NR==1{serial_number=$2}NR==2{device_id=$0}NR==3{print serial_number",\t"device_id",\t"  $2}' Disptelnet.dat >>dispositivoss.csv
```

and this is what i get:

```
serial_number,device_id,ip_address
2223178555, Joshep, 22.36
2221471162,   Cesar,    14.22
```

I've also tried with \t, \s \k

Comment: is there just one entry in the .dat file? if not, how are they separated?

Comment: the .dat file only contains one entry, the .csv could contain 0 to n entries.
both files are exactly as in the post.
line number 2 in .dat file does not has a "name label" but name is always there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simplistic approach, using `awk`

```
awk 'NR==1{phone=$2}NR==2{name=$0}NR==3{print phone","name","$2}' cesar.dat >>phones.csv
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, but i would like to keep the spaces before name and size, i just update the question in order to be clear